# Is there anyway I can modify a XML tab by code in a ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I have an Action Bar with 3 XML tabs (ViewPager)... Can I modify the third XML by code or link the XML to a public class? The only thing I can do is to modify the buttons or background by android XML code! This is the code:

```
    public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);
                                                int tabLayout = 0;

                switch (position) {

                case 0:

                tabLayout = R.layout.tabpracticeonenote1;

                break;

                case 1:

                tabLayout = R.layout.tabpracticeonenote2;

                break;

                case 2:

                tabLayout = R.layout.tabpracticeonenote3;


                break;

                }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. You should explain better what you want to do.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! What I really want to do is to modify the third tabLayout (tabpracticeonenote3.xml), but i can't manage to modify by code!

Comment: Do you want to modify the structure of that layout? If yes then using a single fragment which loads a xml layout based on some condition isn't the best approach. You should have a fragment for each tab that you can then modify as you want more easily.